# Delete records in ManyToMany relationship spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have Two Entities. A and B. Relationship between `A` and `B` is `@ManyToMany`. So I have introduced Third entity `C` for `@ManyToMany` relationship as it needed for project.

My Entity classes are look like following.

```
@Entity
class A
{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
    List<C> cList;
}

@Entity
class B
{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "b")
    List<C> cList;
}

@Entity
class C
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ref_a")
    A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ref_b")
    B b;
}
```

Now, I want to delete record of entity `A` or `B` then it should delete respective record from `C`.
But when I delete record of `A` or `B` it shows

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

What other configuration it need to delete record from `A` or `B` and it will also delete respective record from `C`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create an entity to map the Many To Many table. The ManyToMany JPA annotation is there. Here is a sample of how to do it.

```
@Entity
public class Team {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, mappedBy="teams")
    private List<Match> matches;
}

@Entity
public class Match {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinTable(
            name="MATCH_TEAM",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MATCH_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TEAM_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
    private List<Team> teams;
}
```